# 15 years old card game with ancient battles theme and complex mechanics

Tags: identify-this-game

I used to play a PC game about 15 years ago that was based on a card game. 
I remember the following details:

- It contained cards
- It had ancient battles theme
- Each card represented battle unit
- There were factions like Romans, Carthageneans, Egyptians, Maccabeans and more.
- Some factions were inherently stronger than others. Battles were often assymetrical.
- Game battles were based on real battles.
- Some of the units were - heavy infantry, light infantry, phalanx, chariot, elephants.
- Each player would put the cards in a row against the oponents row.
- There was some rule on when to draw the cards from your own deck and how to put them.
- Each card could attack only 3 cards which are approximate to it.
- If a card was attacked from leftmost or rightmost, it was considered "flanked" and depending on the unit, the attack might have got significant bonuses.
- The combat mechanics were not easy to understand

I've searched google with all the keywords I could think of, but can't find it.
Any idea?

Comment: Sounds a little bit like Battle Line

Comment: @user30903, Thanks for introducing me to this game, it looks interesting! However, it is not it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, after the comment about "Battle Line" (Thanks to @user30903) I started to view the game description and suddenly I saw a war unit called hoplite... and then I recalled.

The PC game is called "[Hoplites](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/34694/hoplites)". It is completely [free](http://digilander.libero.it/zak965/hoplites/PortableHoplites.zip) and its manual is available [here](http://digilander.libero.it/zak965/manual.pdf). It is based on a board game called [SPQR](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/21551/spqr-deluxe-edition). The game "Battle Line" is from the same company.